# Draw A Custom Table In Windows Forms

Tags: c#

I want to draw a custom table to be a way similar to this one in the picture

[image]

I have tried the TableLayoutPanel but i can't get something similar to this one, So your help would be very appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you plan to accomplish with the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a `TableLayoutPanel` and change the [ColumnSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171687%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of the controls inside the panel.

Check [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2006/04/05/winforms-autolayout-basics-tablelayoutpanel.aspx)

Comment: but i still can't get a result like the image i have posted ! any ideas ?

Comment: it ended that i created 3 vertical tables and aligned them perfectly to appear that it is 1 table, then i sliced up the middle one just as in the picture. It works but i think there is a way better

Comment: @RuneS I could send you a sample if you could just tell me what controls should be inside that table.

Comment: it would be labels, textboxes, and picture boxes each in a cell. for instance i wanna a table just like the one i have posted with controls in it any kind of controls.

Comment: well you are more than thanked for you very very very useful help i really can't thank you...

Answer (score 2):

You can create an RDLC report and use the Table Control in that, that is really customizable to the extent you need.

Perhaps you'd be considering to populate the table with some data, I am pretty sure RDLC will come in handy for that cause.

You can go thru this link on how to work with it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067%28v=vs.80%29.aspx